# Guest user permissions with Rails and CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

Do I need to define permissions for creating user for guest? I mean can he sign up with out this permissions?

Comment: reasonable assumption

Comment: There are a lot of examles without such guest permissons(cancan official description, railscast #192). But into gem canard description, I have found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relative to what you need, but I would say in most cases you do not set up specific permissions for guest users. Have a look at how Ryan Bates suggest handeling it with CanCan http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

In effect you could capture it like this in your initialisation of your Ability model:

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :admin
      #admin permissions
    else
      #default permissions
    end
  end
```